# Angular Upload Folder to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: angular, azure, azure-storage

In our application we let the user select a folder, and then we upload all the files in this folder to our server (Azure App Service) as a multipart formData.

We work now on optimizing this process, and upload the files to Azure Storage instead.

In Azure blob storage SDK for JS we can find methods to upload a single file.
Is there a way to upload multiple files to specific folder in an Azure Blob Container, in one request?

Answer (score 0):

As i know, There is no direct way to do this. You can go through the azure storage SDK for details.

But its achievable, you need to send all the files at once and then you should loop over them in your backend.

Comment: We do not want to upload the files to our backend anymore. we want to upload it directly from the frontend to Azure Storage.
What do you mean by "You can go through the azure storage SDK for details."? which details should I look for in there?

Comment: Uploading directly from your frontend may not be a secured way! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs